# How can I assure even heat distribution in a glass bundt pan with a closed tube?

Tags: glass

Have a beautiful borosilicate glass bundt pan with which I have had mixed results when baking. My Kugelhopfs and babkas turn out well sometimes and so do other bundts like the Apple Dapple cake etc.. Yet at times the cakes turn out a bit raw or underdone around the 'closed' tube area. I bake successfully in glass pans, adjusting heat times and settings. But these bundt pans have me puzzled. To achieve consistent results, I use the same methods, times and heat settings as for the successful bakes. Sometimes the cakes turn out fine, at other times raw, gooey dough around the center tube results. I'm no engineer but I think perhaps the tube shouldn't be closed? Is there any way I can compensate for the lack of even heat distribution, especially around the center tube? Haven't tried using a pie drip catcher (hole in center) to set the bundt pan on; that's my next test. If you have a solution that really works, please share it. Hate having to wonder if my cakes are done, especially gift cakes for the holidays. Thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: It's beautiful - So it's art, or a gelatine mold, and a metal pan with a hole in the center will work far more reliably for cake-baking - which it appears to be bad at. Kinda like the practical value of glass slippers as shoes...

Comment: What do you mean by 'closed tube'?

Comment: @GdD a Bundt pan is a torus. This one has the tubular part making doughnut-hole or bagel-hole in the middle of the cake closed off, rather than being open for airflow through it, evidently. So the cake is a torus but the pan isn't, topologically-speaking.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense @Ecnerwal. Seems like an odd design choice.

Comment: @Sophia, does your oven have a convection (i.e. fan) mode?

Comment: I'm pretty certain it's called "Gugelhupf"

Comment: This sort of construction? https://www.etsy.com/uk/listing/1506545235/vintage-1940s-queen-anne-budt-pan?ga_order=most_relevant&ga_search_type=all&ga_view_type=gallery&ga_search_query=glass+bundt+pan&ref=sr_gallery-1-27&organic_search_click=1

Comment: I'm wondering if there would be some way of making a metal (aluminium probably) stand with a plate base and a cylinder that fits loosely inside the tube part.  Preheat that, then put the pan over the top of it, to deliver heat faster in the middle

Comment: Try getting a piece of metal, round, and smaller in diameter than the inner diameter of the pan.  Put it in the oven while it is heating up (so that it is at the oven's ambient temperature when you put the bundt pan in).  Place the bundt pan in the oven _around_ the metal.  I have no experience with this (or any idea whether it will work or not), but it will make the empty space hotter than the rest of the pan - at least to start with

Comment: @Ecnerwal It still would be good to know if the center is a solid mass of glass, a tube closed off at the top or a tube closed off at the bottom (or something else). -- If it's a tube closed off at the top, you'll get different performance if you put it directly on an open rack vs. on a baking sheet vs. a pie drip tray with an open center.

Comment: @Hobbamok [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gugelhupf) gives at least eight different regional/dialectical variations for spelling, and a quick Google search shows that the "Kugelhopf" is well attested (e.g. [King Arthur Flour](https://www.kingarthurbaking.com/recipes/naturally-leavened-brioche-style-kugelhopf-recipe) and [New York Times](https://cooking.nytimes.com/recipes/4207-kugelhopf))

Comment: @R.M. ok, didn't look at Wikipedia, but Google yielded pretty much no results so I was sceptical

Answer (score 6):

I don’t think it has much to do with lack of air circulation from the closed tube, but with the gigantic mass of glass in the center. That’ll take a long time to heat up, retarding the cooking in that area.

For forgiving recipes which are fine with extended cooking, consider increasing the cooking time. For recipes which need to be cooked thoroughly without being overcooked, consider buying a metal pan.

Comment: Might it not also be an option to preheat the pan in the oven before adding in the cake mixture?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Maybe? I wouldn't really want to grease, prepare, and fill a piping hot chunk of glass with batter. It's not normally how I bake cakes.

Comment: True, if you’re greasing ‘by hand’ (as opposed to spraying, for example), it could get both messy and painful rather quickly. Didn’t consider that.

Comment: You *could* grease -> heat -> fill but that still seems dangerous